# Different ways to express expectation of a r.v. using integrals

Tags: integration, probability-theory, expected-value

Given the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$, I have been given the following definition of expectation of a random variable:
$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\mu=\int_{\Omega}X\,d\mathbb{P}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,dP_X(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,dF(x)$$
I am not sure if I understand these equalities. I think
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,dP_X(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}x\cdot f(x)\, dx$$
because $P_X(x)$ is the function that assigns to each $x$ a "weight" equal to its probability. However, I don't understand how it is possible that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\cdot f(x) \,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,dF(x)$$
because $F(x)$ is the function that gives each $x$ a weight equal to $P_X(-\infty, x]$.
Could someone help me with this?

Comment: That is true if and only if dF= f(x)dx which is the same as $\frac{dF}{dx}=  f(x)$ but you don't seem be saying what the relationship between "f" and "F" is  or  even what they mean in relation to P.

Comment: the notations $dP_X$ and $dF_X$ represent the same thing